# Смущает "серьёзная ответственность"; какая она ещё может быть? Кроме "большой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Дело в том, что в своё время я действительно рисковала и привела всех
>   в изумление, когда решила рожать дома в воде, потому что, конечно, это
>   очень **ответственный** шаг. Но, я считаю, абсолютно верный, потому
>   что те люди и те мои подруги, которые последовали этому примеру, в
>   итоге получили ту же массу удовольствия, что и я. Я вижу не одно
>   подтверждение. Да, безусловно, это **серьёзная ответственность, очень
>   большая.**

И ответственностей две...

Чем можно заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакое *количественное* описание ответственности *не уточнит* читателю, насколько же она велика - размер субъективен, и достаточно употребить **одно слово** для размера (*большая, серьёзная, огромная*) и при необходимости добавить определение аспекта ответственности (кармическая, моральная, социальная, финансовая и пр.). *Конкретизировать* ответственность можно только контекстом (*перед кем* это ответственность и *каковы риски* в случае чего).

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в своё время я действительно рисковала и привела всех в изумление, когда решила рожать дома в воде, потому что, конечно, это очень **серьезный и продуманный шаг.** Но, я считаю, абсолютно верный, потому что те люди и те мои подруги, которые последовали этому примеру, в итоге получили ту же массу удовольствия, что и я. Я вижу не одно подтверждение. **Но, безусловно, это моральная ответственность, очень большая.**

Comment: "Продуманный шаг" не очень подходит в качестве объяснения, почему это приводит в изумление и означает риск.

Comment: А что тут не так? Человек может идти на риск обдуманно, а для окружающих это может быть полной неожиданностью.

Comment: Может быть; я спорить не стану. У меня возникли сомнения в логике такого обоснования (возможно, вследствие проф.деформации).

Answer (score 1):

**Да, безусловно, это серьёзная ответственность, очень большая.**

Предлагаю: "Но это, безусловно, огромная ответственность".

"Два в одном", зато это стандартный оборот, и он полностью соответствует авторской задумке.